# Latex repeat equation numbering (unwanted)

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm using the `equation` environment in my latex document. All went ok until half a chapter when I find the two equation have the same equation number (3.44). Why could this happens?
Moreover, from that point to the end of the document, all the equations that are within the same `subsection/section` have the same numbering.

This is the crucial point of the document:
 At first

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbf { L } \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } = \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } \mathbf { C } _ { \mathcal { K } }
\end{equation}
```

that currently follow the equation numbering order and it is (3.44). Then 
I insert two equation that must not to be numbered, thus I used the tag environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\quad &\min _ { \mathbf { L } \in \mathbb { R } ^ { N \times N } , \mathrm { C } _ { \mathcal { K } } \in \mathbb { R } ^ { K \times K } } f ( \mathbf { L } , \mathbf { Y } , \hat { \mathbf { S } } )
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L}$}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\notag
\quad \quad & & & & \left. \begin{array} { c l } { \text { s.t. } } & { \mathbf { L } \in \mathcal { L } , \operatorname { tr } ( \mathbf { L } ) = p } \\ { } & { \mathbf { L } \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } = \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } \mathbf { C } _ { \mathcal { K } } , \mathbf { C } _ { \mathcal { K } \succeq } \mathbf { 0 } } \end{array} \right\} \triangleq \mathcal { X } \left( \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\quad &\min _ { \mathbf { L } \in \mathbb { R } ^ { N \times N } \atop \mathrm { C } _ { \mathcal { K } } \in \mathbb { R } ^ { K \times K } } f _ { 1 } ( \mathbf { L } , \mathbf { Y } , \mu ) \triangleq \mathrm { TV } ( \mathbf { L } , \mathbf { Y } ) + \mu \| \mathbf { L } \| _ { F } ^ { 2 }
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L_{1}}$}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\notag
 \left. \begin{array} { c l } { \text { s.t. } } & \quad \left( \mathbf { L } , \mathbf { C } _ { \mathcal { K } } \right) \in \mathcal { X } \left( \hat { \mathbf { U } } _ { \mathcal { K } } \right)
\end{equation}
```

that has no equation number but the tag filled. Then when writing

```
\begin{equation}
\operatorname { tr } \left( \mathbf { Y } ^ { T } \mathbf { L Y } \right) = \operatorname { tr } \left( \mathbf { S } _ { \mathcal { K } } ^ { T } \mathbf { \Lambda } _ { \mathcal { K } } \mathbf { S } _ { \mathcal { K } } \right) = \operatorname { tr } \left( \hat { \mathbf { S } } _ { \mathcal { K } } ^ { T } \mathbf { C } _ { \mathcal { K } } \hat { \mathbf { S } } _ { \mathcal { K } } \right)
\end{equation}
```

it has still equation number 3.44.
Why?

EDIT: I wrote the two consecutive equation environemt to obtain the following effect

[image]

Comment: It is strange unless you have some special changes. Please show us a compilable code so that we can have some tests.

Comment: Why isn't it compilable?

Comment: Of course all the above codes are not compilable, because they don't have `\documentclass{}`, `\begin{document}`, etc.

Comment: You get a *huge* number of errors from that input. Whatever happens next is not reliable until you fix the errors.

Comment: If you want a totally unnumbered equation, use the starred form of the environment.  Al;so, rather than putting two equation environments directly after one another, consider using one of the multi0-line display environments provided by `amsmath`.  (To see the documentation, at a command line prompt, type `texdoc amsmath'.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would like to write the constraint set of the optimization problem in the same equation environments, but it's not aligned as aspected and I decided to use two... I have edited my questions showing which kind of mathematical formulation I would like to have

Comment: @egreg Could you kindly tell me which are the errors and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a *huge* number of errors from that input. Whatever happens next is not reliable until you fix the errors.

Here's a fixed version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\min_{\substack{
  \mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \\
  \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}
}} f(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y},\hat{\mathbf{S}})
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L}$}
\\
\notag
&\quad
\left.\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
\text{s.t.} & \mathbf{L}\in\mathcal{L},\tr(\mathbf{L})=p\\
            & \mathbf{L}\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}}=
              \hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}}\mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}},
              \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}\succeq\mathbf{0}}
\end{array}\right\}
\triangleq\mathcal{X}(\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\\[2ex]
&\min_{\substack{
  \mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \\
  \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}
}} f_{1}(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y},\mu)\triangleq
  \mathrm{TV}(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y})+\mu\|\mathbf{L}\|_{F}^{2}
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L_{1}}$}
\\
\notag
&\quad
\,\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
\text{s.t.} & (\mathbf{L},\mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}})\in\mathcal{X}
              (\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\end{array}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\tr(\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{LY})=
\tr(\mathbf{S}_{\mathcal{K}}^{T}
    \mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathcal{K}}
    \mathbf{S}_{\mathcal{K}})=
\tr(\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{\mathcal{K}}^{T}
    \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}
    \hat{\mathbf{S}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With different alignment. A couple of tricks are needed to move `s.t` to the left with the brace on the right hand side.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hphantom{\text{s.t.}\quad}
&\min_{\substack{
  \mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \\
  \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}
}} f(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y},\hat{\mathbf{S}})
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L}$}
\\
\notag
&\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
 \makebox[0pt][r]{s.t.\quad}
 \mathbf{L}\in\mathcal{L},\tr(\mathbf{L})=p\\
 \mathbf{L}\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}}=
   \hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}}\mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}},
   \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}\succeq\mathbf{0}}
\end{array}\right\}
\triangleq\mathcal{X}(\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\\[2ex]
&\min_{\substack{
  \mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N} \\
  \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}
}} f_{1}(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y},\mu)\triangleq
  \mathrm{TV}(\mathbf{L},\mathbf{Y})+\mu\|\mathbf{L}\|_{F}^{2}
\tag{$\mathcal{P}_{L_{1}}$}
\\
\notag
&\makebox[0pt][r]{s.t.\quad}
 (\mathbf{L},\mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}})\in\mathcal{X}
 (\hat{\mathbf{U}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\tr(\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{LY})=
\tr(\mathbf{S}_{\mathcal{K}}^{T}
    \mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathcal{K}}
    \mathbf{S}_{\mathcal{K}})=
\tr(\hat{\mathbf{S}}_{\mathcal{K}}^{T}
    \mathbf{C}_{\mathcal{K}}
    \hat{\mathbf{S}}_{\mathcal{K}})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question has been edited to show the desired alignment.  You may want to modify your examples.  (I'd do it, but I don't yet have a working tex system.)

Comment: @egreg After these changes, the equation numbering order is correct. Thank you so much. Which could be the reason anyway?

Comment: @Alberto I added a different alignment. The errors you got put LaTeX out of synch and it wasn't able to step correctly the equation number.